# Cipher feedback mode is susceptible to replay attacks?

Tags: block-cipher

In a [Korean examination](https://eduon.com/itembank/itemlist/1/2672/), the correct answer was "Cipher feedback mode is known to be susceptible to replay attacks". But when I read the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation), it only mentions that for the ECB mode. Is cipher feedback mode also susceptible to replay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note first the wording of the Wikipedia article:

> ECB mode can also make protocols without integrity protection **even more** susceptible to replay attacks

That is they state that, if ECB is used, it can be even easier to perform a replay attack, due to the ability to 'cut and paste' blocks of ECB-encrypted ciphertext. This does however not mean that only ECB is susceptible.

Indeed none of the blockcipher modes of operation (nor encryption in general) provide any built-in protection against replay attacks. If an adversary observes a ciphertext of a symmetric cryptosystem, they are able to store it, and send it to one of the involved parties at a later time.

Authenticated modes (such as GCM) do however ensure **integrity** of the messages, which prevents an adversary from modifying the ciphertext before sending it to one of the parties.

Protection against replay attacks is usually done on the protocol level, by including a nonce, counter, or timestamp in the plaintext messages.